# get attribute from instance variable using jQuery and Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a this working countdown timer in jQuery but for now I'm just statically setting the target date but I need to set the target date using an attribute from my instance variable, but **the value is not showed on the page** so I guess can't get it directly by using `$("#date")`...I need something like this:

```
$('#countdown_dashboard').countDown({
    targetDate: {
       'min': my_instance_date_min
    }
)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want an instance variable in your controller to determine the target date for your countdown timer. If that's the case, then just render it in your view either as a hidden form element, or as a page element with `display:none`. Consider this code:

```
<form>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "ivar_date", @ivar_date %>
</form>
```

That gets you your hidden element with the value of in instance variable. Then in your jQuery, you can just:

```
'min': $('#ivar_date').value()
```

to get the date in your timer.